# how to read a Hjson file in python (Pycharm)?

Tags: python, hjson

i would like to know how to read a '.Hjson' file in python ?. I have obtained a dataset in Hjson format and want to perform analysis on that using Python such as obtain x and y .The data looks like this:

```
Project:{ centerX:0, centerY:0, scaleX:0.37, scaleY:-0.21, angle:0 }
Tiles:[
    { x:-1.292007, y:0.9794083, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:-1.413942, y:-1.083101, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:1.430358, y:1.154297, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:1.862622, y:0.1652414, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:1.726217, y:-0.8780851, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:0.572257, y:0.9339409, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:1.188227, y:0.4919281, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:0.05530262, y:0.6475933, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:-0.8808339, y:0.4798487, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:-0.3528011, y:0.1176641, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:0.774766, y:-0.06418264, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:-1.037972, y:-0.2158461, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:-0.1206918, y:-0.6493511, width:0.2, height:0.2}
    { x:0.9421639, y:-0.5510759, width:0.2, height:0.2}
```

thanks >

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: yes, but i am dummy in programming and i cannot figured out how to do it

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i try do use this information http://hjson.org but i cannot do it

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

`import hjson`

`def openHJSON():`
    `deserializeFileName = 'yourfile.hjson'`
     `with open(deserializeFileName) as deserializeFile:`

`deserializeObj = hjson.loads(deserializeFile.read())`
     `for someObject in deserializeObj["someKey"]:`

`# Do it til you're satisfied.`